# Firebase: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'BFunctions.hallo.DCreationDate'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am struggling with an issue of my Angular application.
Within my form I am sending data to my Firebase database. I also want to save the creation date in the database. But apparently it doesn't work anymore - it did before.
I do not understand the error message at all:

```
ERROR Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains undefined in property 'BFunctions.hallo.DCreationDate'
    at Object.t.validateFirebaseData (validation.js:103)
    at validation.js:149
    at Object.t.forEach (obj.js:37)
    at Object.t.validateFirebaseData (validation.js:132)
    at Object.t.validateFirebaseDataArg (validation.js:91)
    at t.set (Reference.js:114)
    at BusinessFunctionComponent.fbPostData (business-function.component.ts:67)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (BusinessFunctionComponent.html:17)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13255)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:14740)
```

This is my code of my `business-function.component.ts` (I deleted the unrelevant parts):

```
declare var firebase: any;
const d: Date = new Date();


@Component({
  selector: 'app-business-function',
  templateUrl: './business-function.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./business-function.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [DataService, SearchNamePipe]
})
export class BusinessFunctionComponent implements OnInit {


  name:String;
  descr:String;
  jahr;
  monat;
  tag;
  stunde;
  minute;
  datum;
  liste = [];
  isDesc: boolean = false;
  column: string = 'Name';
  direction: number;



  constructor(
    private dataService: DataService,
    private router: Router, 
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private searchName: SearchNamePipe) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.jahr=d.getFullYear();
    this.monat=d.getMonth();
    this.minute='hallo';
    this.fbGetData();
    console.log(this.liste)
  }

fbGetData(){

  firebase.database().ref().child('/BFunctions/').orderByChild('CFlag').equalTo('active').
  on('child_added', (snapshot) => {  
  //firebase.database().ref('/BFunctions/').orderByKey().on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
 // alter code ... neuer Code nimmt nur die Validen mit dem X Flag    
  this.liste.push(snapshot.val())
  })
}


fbPostData(name,descr){
 // firebase.database().ref('/BFunctions/').push({Descr: descr, Name: name});
 firebase.database().ref().child('/BFunctions/').child(name).set({
 AName: name ,BDescr: descr, CFlag: 'active', DCreationDate: this.datum //, created: this.creationDate, altered: 'none', removed: 'none'
    });
    this.name = '';
    this.descr = '';

}


}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I appreciate all answers!

Comment: `this.datum` is undefined.

Comment: jahr:String;
  monat:TypeOfYour;
  tag:TypeOfYour;
  stunde:TypeOfYour;
  minute:TypeOfYour;
  datum:TypeOfYour;